# How to find records that have any duplicate data using Active Record

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, duplicates, aggregate-functions

How to find records with duplicate values in any column using Activerecord or SQL?

```
SELECT leads.id, leads.name, leads.email, leads.created_at, array_agg(tn2.id) as ids
FROM "leads" join leads tn2
    on leads.name = tn2.name
      or leads.cpf_cnpj = tn2.cpf_cnpj
      or leads.email = tn2.email
      or leads.phone -> 'cellphone' = tn2.phone -> 'cellphone'
      or leads.phone -> 'residence' = tn2.phone -> 'residence'
      or leads.phone -> 'commercial' = tn2.phone -> 'commercial' 
GROUP BY leads.id  ORDER BY leads.created_at DESC
```

Using `array_agg` I want only ids from repeated objects, but it gives me from all records. 
Currently, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: By coding. What have you tried?

Comment: You seem to be missing this vital condition from the `WHERE` clause: `leads.id <> tn2.id`

Comment: You did not phrase a proper *question*. How is the array related to your question? You did not provide your version of Postgres nor the table definition.

Answer (score 1):

> How to find records with duplicate values in any column?

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.email, l.created_at, array_agg(l2.id) AS ids
FROM   leads l
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   leads 
   WHERE  id <> l.id 
   AND   (
          name = l.name    
   OR     cpf_cnpj = l.cpf_cnpj
   OR     email = l.email
   OR     phone->'cellphone'  = l.phone->'cellphone'
   OR     phone->'residence'  = l.phone->'residence'
   OR     phone->'commercial' = l.phone->'commercial'
         )
   );
```

But it seems like you want something different:

> How to get an array of IDs for each row from rows that have the same value in at least one of several given columns, youngest entry first?

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.email, l.created_at
     , array_agg(l2.id  ORDER BY l2.created_at DESC NULL LAST) AS dupe_ids
FROM   leads l
JOIN   leads l2 ON l2.id <> l.id 
      AND   (
              l2.name = l.name    
       OR     l2.cpf_cnpj = l.cpf_cnpj
       OR     l2.email = l.email
       OR     l2.phone->'cellphone'  = l.phone->'cellphone'
       OR     l2.phone->'residence'  = l.phone->'residence'
       OR     l2.phone->'commercial' = l.phone->'commercial'
             )
GROUP   BY l.id
ORDER   BY l.created_at DESC NULL LAST;
```

Assuming `id` is the primary key.